# C - meaning of wait(NULL) when executing fork() in parallel

Tags: c, multiprocessing, fork

In the code below, do the forks actually run in parallel or one after another?

What is the meaning of `wait(NULL)` ?

(The program creates an n number of child processes, n is supplied via command line)

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    int i, pid;

    for(i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0) {
            printf("Error occured");
            exit(1);
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            printf("Child (%d): %d\n", i + 1, getpid());
            exit(0); 
        } else  {
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part of `man wait` did you not understand?

Comment: Or, depending on your man pages, `man 2 wait` :)

Comment: I'm just wondering if in the code above - it will wait for the child to finish before creating a new child?

Comment: The parent waits for a child to die on each iteration.  Since there's only one child that can die on the first iteration, the second iteration doesn't start until the first child has died.  The `wait(NULL)` means "I do not care to know which child died or what exit status the child exited with, or even whether there was a child to wait for".

Comment: So it doesn't wait for the child to finish before creating a new child - it just creates them all at once and sits there without caring when and which child finishes - is that right?

Comment: Perhaps the previous comments were too brief.  The manual page for the `wait()` syscall explains exactly what it does.  You can read it via the `man` command or by googling for it.  If you still have questions after reading the docs, then ask a more specific question.

Comment: Anyway, have you tried running it to see what it does?  Adding extra print statements to probe the issue, perhaps? No?

Comment: I did, they print them one after another - which hints me that they are not executing in parallel, but rather in a sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the 'man' comments - I did read it, forking is just a quite hard concept for me to grasp and I'd rather learn it by example then from trying to  understand the man description.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about spelling out what's already perfectly well documented by the standard manuals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They do run in parallel, up until the point that one of them waits.

`wait(NULL)` or more accurately `wait(0)` means wait until a state change in the child process.  To find out about Unix / Linux C api calls, type `man <function Name>` on the command line.  You'll need to get used to reading those pages, so better start now.

In your case

```
man wait
```

would have given you what you needed.

Since you've only `fork(...)`ed once, you have only one child.  The parent waits until it changes state, and since the child's state during the fork is the same as the parent's state prior to the fork (that of *running*), the likely outcome is that the parent waits until the child dies.  Then the parent will continue executing, but since it doesn't have much to do after the `wait(...)` call, it will quickly exit too.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. (You have a typo in the third code block: main -> man)

Comment: What happens if there is no child process at all but the main process has a `wait(NULL)` ?

Comment: @Genius Many implementations just treat the `wait(...)` as a NOOP.  Not sure if that's required by a standard, but it does make sense in a way.  If you have no children to wait for, they've all completed.  https://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/wait.html is the reference that says it will not block.