# C - using exec() instead of system()

Tags: c, exec, fork, system

In the following code:

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    int i, pid, status;

    for(i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0) {
            printf("Error occured");
            exit(1);
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            status = system("./frun test.txt 1");
            if (status != 0)
                printf("ERROR, exited with %d\n", status);
            else
                printf("SUCCESS, exited with %d\n", status); // 0
            exit(0); 
        } else  {
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am using system() to run a program called 'frun'
My question is - how would I change the code to use one of the exec() family functions instead?

My main problem is that I need to get the exit code of the program and I can't find a way to do it with exec(), while system() just returns the exit status.

Comment: Wait, is this just [a duplicate of your question from just earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26497315/596781)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about spelling out what's already perfectly well documented by the standard manuals.

Comment: I disagree, having read the manual - I still don't understand how to alter the code so it acts the same way, but using exec() instead of system(). I don't want you to write the solution, just hint me at what needs to be changed.

Comment: You need to use `fork()`, one of the `exec*()` functions, and `wait()` or `waitpid()`.

Comment: @YemSalat: It's not just a simple change. This stuff is fairly subtle and you need to be clear about how the Posix process model works if you want to do all this yourself. Jonathan said the right entry points, but this isn't a walk in the park. Expect to meet zombies, orphans, get stop at signals by masked men and get killed by pipes a lot.

Comment: By the way, you should probably return something from main().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the manual pages for wait and exec.

You wait on the process created from forking and execing (recall that exec replaces the current process, so you must fork to get its exit code). This is from the man page for wait:

> Regardless of its value, this information  may  be  interpreted  using  the  following
>              macros,  which  are  defined in `<sys/wait.h>` and evaluate to integral expressions; the
>              `stat_val` argument is the integer value pointed to by `stat_loc`.
>
> - `WIFEXITED(stat_val)`
>     Evaluates to a non-zero value if status was returned for a  child  process  that
>                  terminated normally.
> - `WEXITSTATUS(stat_val)`
>     If  the  value  of  `WIFEXITED(stat_val)` is non-zero, this macro evaluates to the
>                  low-order 8 bits of the status argument that the child process passed to _exit()
>                  or `exit()`, or the value the child process returned from `main()`.
> - `WIFSIGNALED(stat_val)`
>     Evaluates  to  a  non-zero value if status was returned for a child process that
>                  terminated due to the receipt of a signal that was not caught (see `<signal.h>`).
> - `WTERMSIG(stat_val)`
>     If the value of `WIFSIGNALED(stat_val)` is non-zero, this macro evaluates  to  the
>                  number of the signal that caused the termination of the child process.
> - `WIFSTOPPED(stat_val)`
>     Evaluates to a non-zero value if status was returned for a child process that is
>                  currently stopped.
> - `WSTOPSIG(stat_val)`
>     If the value of `WIFSTOPPED(stat_val)` is non-zero, this macro  evaluates  to  the
>                  number of the signal that caused the child process to stop.
> - `WIFCONTINUED(stat_val)`
>     Evaluates  to a non-zero value if status was returned for a child process that
>                  has continued from a job control stop.

In your case you'd probably want to use `WEXITSTATUS(stat_val)` to get the 8 bit exit code.

You call `waitpid(pid, stat_loc, options)` where you'd pass the `pid` returned from `fork()`, a pointer to a local int (where the status is stored), and your options flags (or 0). You would do this is in the branch where `pid != 0`, since this is the original process. The original process calling `fork()` (where `pid == 0`) would call `exec` and thus be replaced by the `exec`'d command.

Here is a pseudo-example that you can adapt to your code:

```
pid_t pid;
int status;
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
        exec(/*look up the different functions in the exec family and how to use them*/);
}
else if (pid < 0)
{
        //uh oh
}
else
{
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        printf("Exited with %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
}
```

Though you should check the result of waitpid.

Comment: Thanks, but where do I get the stat_val from?

Comment: Would it be something like: `int status = exec("run", "test.txt", "1", NULL); wait(&status); WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0 { //SUCCESS }` ?

Comment: @YemSalat: No.  If successful, `exec()` doesn't return.  If `exec()` returns, you know it failed.  Your child process (created by `fork()`) does the `exec()` and exits (probably with an error message) if `exec()` returns.  Your parent process does `wait()` or `waitpid()` as described by Trey.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But how do I determine whether `exec()` went successfully (exited with 0)?

Comment: exec only returns if it fails, otherwise the current process is replaced and exec doesn't return. This is why you must fork a new process and replace it with exec.

Comment: @YemSalat: the parent process waits for the child to die (this is a morbid business you're entering upon), and the `wait*()` function reports on the exit status of the child (if the child exited; if the child died from being signalled, you get information about the signal that killed it).  You need to find and read a basic Unix manual; this is basic Unix (POSIX, Linux) stuff.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I am finally starting to understand this. Could you please explain how `waitpid()` with `WEXITSTATUS()` would be used in the parent process to determine if exec successfully replaced the child process and ran without errors? [EDIT] I got the part that the child would be replaced on successful run, but how do I get it's id to check in the parent?

Comment: In the example I provided you'd check if WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0. In *nix they use the mentality that a process can be successful one way and fail many ways, so an exit code of 0 means success, !0 is some specific (hopefully) kind of failure.

Comment: @Trey, thanks for all your help! Just the last stupid question - where do I get the status from if `exec()` did not return anything?

Comment: That's what the second parameter in waitpid is for. It sets the value of the pointed-to int to some representation of the status of the process, of which you pass to the macros like WEXITSTATUS to pull out specific values from. You're forking to create another process to be replaced/consumed by exec, and in the parent process you waitpid on the pid of the process created by fork (which is now whatever you exec'd) and get the status.