# How many processes will be created?

Tags: c, unix, process, fork, wait

Excluding the initial parent process, how many processes will be created by the following piece of code:

```
fork();
wait(0);
fork();
wait(0);
fork();
```

I was thinking of 7 processes because the father always waits for the child to end, but the child never exits. So it would be a 2**n - 1.

Comment: Looks like a homework question. Please edit your post and add your own solution, otherwise, you'll be downvoted...

Comment: @Yan he provided his attempt, so I think it's fine now. I posted an answer, what do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

Every call to a fork function will create a new process. Every process (including the parent) will execute the code following its fork call. Every parent will wait for its child to die (remember that when a child calls fork, it also becomes a parent).

Draw a schema to be sure:

[image]

This gives as 7 processes, excluding the parent process.

Read the tree from its *rightmost* branch, and then maybe the following comments make sense:

```
fork();  // Process 'c0' was created
wait(0); // Parent process 'p' waits for its child 'c0' to change state.
fork();  // c1, c4
wait(0); // c0, p
fork();  // c2, c3, c5, c6
```

The <kbd>[Online Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2pW2vL0GezH8RROE)</kbd> I created with printing statements and processes' IDs confirms that.

---

Reminder of the `0` argument in [`wait()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait):

> wait for any child process whose process group ID is equal to that of the calling process.

Read more in [C - meaning of wait(NULL) when executing fork() in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497315/c-meaning-of-waitnull-when-executing-fork-in-parallel).

Notice that the number of processes won't change if you comment out the wait calls.

Comment: So the parent waits for the child to die, but in this case it never happens. Right?

Comment: It will happen @DoullOwen, since I assume that after the last `fork()` comes the `return 0;` statement of the `main()`, so they terminate their execution when they reach the end of the main function.